# Ant set up - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache, ant, installation

I downloaded ant and started by setting up ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME. Then I added their bin folder into my PATH.
At this point I tried to send the command ant -version and instead of getting the version number of it, I get this error:

```
bash-4.1$ ant -version

java.lang.NullPointerException

      at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:267)
      at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution to this problem?

@Chad Nouis here are some of the lines you asked for

[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from /users/level3/1104634v/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from /users/level3/1104634v/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar]

[Loaded org.apache.tools.ant.launch.LaunchException from file:/users/level3/1104634v/Documents/PSD3/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.tools.ant.launch.AntMain from file:/users/level3/1104634v/Documents/PSD3/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar]

Comment: You might try adding -debug and -verbose on the command line to get a bit more information.  Never seen this, almost like something is missing.

Comment: Try this: Run `export ANT_OPTS=-verbose:class` and then `ant -version`. This will generate a lot of output. Edit your question and copy the following from the output: 1) A line beginning with `[Loaded java.lang.` and 2) a line beginning with `[Loaded org.apache.tools.ant.`. This will help us understand your environment.

Comment: @ChadNouis There are a lot of lines that start with [Loaded java.lang] and [Loaded org.apache.tools.ant] :S

Comment: @FrancescoPacoVanduynslager Pick any examples of those lines.